# MATLAB: Dynamic heatmap

Tags: matlab, plot, visualization, data-visualization

I have 3D matrix of dimensions **D x D x N**. I want to create a dynamic heatmap to show how it's varying over **N**. Here's the MATLAB code I used to achieve this.

```
for n=1:N
    heatmap(dynamicCov(:,:,n));
    pause(0.5);
end
```

The issue with this code is that for each **n**, it opens a new figure window. I want it to be  updated in the same **Heatmap** window. Is it possible to do that? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: add figure(1) before the line `heatmap(dynamicCov(:,:,n));`. That should do it.

Comment: @Parag Thanks for your comment but it doesn't work. It opens a new window titled 'Heatmap n' for each n.

Comment: You will have to see how HeatMap displays the `obj`. As far as I know, it has a method view and in that method it plots it. So if you could find a way to pass a figure handle to it, it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the undocumented 2nd input to HeatMap that indicates whether a plot should be created or not, and a few other Handle Graphics tricks to get the handle to the figure that is created.  Something like

```
data = rand(20,20,10); % create test data
hmo = HeatMap(data(:,:,1),false); % create but do not plot
plot(hmo); % do the plot
allHFig = findall(0,'Type','figure'); % get handle to all open figures
hFig = allHFig(1); % we want the most recently created figure
for idx = 2:size(data,3)
   hmo = HeatMap(data(:,:,idx),false); % create heatmap but do not plot
   plot(hmo,hFig); % plot to our existing figure
   pause(0.5);
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer worked with a minor edit i.e. in the 2nd line, I had to remove the argument 'false' and removed the 3rd line - `plot(hmo)`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a better and a lot simpler way of doing this. It uses built in `imagesc()` function instead of `HeatMap()` function from Bioinformatics toolbox. The code is as follows:

```
dynamicCov = rand(20,20,10); % create test data
N = size(dynamicCov,3);


for n=1:N
    imagesc(dynamicCov(:,:,n));
    colormap('copper');
    colorbar;
    pause(0.5);
end
```

Reference: http://buli.waw.pl/matlab-heatmap-colormap/